# Posição ScrollTop()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Possuo uma função JavaScript que dá refresh na minha página a cada 15 minutos e estou tentando pegar a última posição da barra de rolagem antes do refresh com o comando jQuery.

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Função refresh:

```
var $myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 900000);

        function myTimer() {
            console.log(scrollPosition);
            loadHs();              

        }
```

Sempre que minha página é recarregada ele já me retorna o valor zero, então gostaria de resgatar o último valor a medida que vou rolando o scroll e setar esse valor resgatado depois do refresh para que ele retorne a posição anterior.

Comment: Tu vai precisar colocar o valor atual do scroll em um cache pra poder resgatar depois do refresh da página.

Comment: Essa linha `localStorage.setItem("timer", true)` é para quê?

Comment: @Sam esta linha já não faz mais parte do meu código

A pergunta também já foi atualizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve a posição num `sessionStorage` (cookie temporário que será apagado ao sair da página) e verifique se existe e é diferente de `0` quando a página for recarregada. Então use o método `window.scrollTo(x,y)` para mover a tela para a posição salva no cookie.

No caso, você só vai alterar o valor do eixo `y` (vertical), deixando o `x` em 0:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // aguarda o carregamento do dom
   var pos = sessionStorage.getItem("posicao"); // atribui o cookie a uma variável
   // se a variável tiver valor, move para a posição salva no cookie
   if(+pos) window.scrollTo(0, pos);
});

var $myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 900000);

function myTimer() {
   var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(); // pega a posição do scroll
   sessionStorage.setItem("posicao", scrollPosition); // salva no cookie
   loadHs();
}
```

Em vez de `sessionStorage`, pode usar `localStorage`, a sintaxe é a mesma. A diferença é que o segundo gera um cookie permanente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém no meu caso ainda continuo recebendo a posição zero

Comment: Tente assim na linha do scrollTo: `if(+pos) setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollTo(0, pos); }, 10);`

Comment: continua retornando zero 

acredito que possa está sendo pelo fato de que quando acesso a pagina pela primeira vez, a barra de rolagem inicia na posição 0 e ja salva esse valor.

se isso estiver acontecendo teria que ter um método que ficasse verificando a posição  ?

Comment: Só salva o valor da posição quando chama a função myTimer(). Como vc está recarregando a página?

Comment: Sim, está correto agora estou conseguindo ver a ultima posição quando uso console.log(), porém a barra não volta para a posição anterior.

Comment: vc colocou o setTimeout como falei?

Comment: tava esquecendo isso, fiz os ajustes e esta funcionando corretamente 

muito obrigado pela ajuda.